# Most optimal way to exhaust a list of lists

Tags: python, list, arraylist, queue, deque

I have a list of lists, built from a 2d array:

I need to popleft a value from each list, in order, until all lists have been exhausted. For example:

```
   4,3,4,9,2,82,5,4,23,3,56,7 for the lists above
```

because this list can become enormous, I want to skip over empty queues. e.g

my solution is to also have a deque of indexes of the queues that still have values with a loop like this:

```
 Loop continuously until we no longer have any dequeues in our queue of indexes to pop from. This will leave the entire list with an empty deque when its done. The alternative is to simply iterate through the list of deque, and remove[index_of_empty_queue] when it is done. This is extremely slow to delete items in a very large list, especially towards the start of the list.
```

Any thoughts on my approach and if there is a better one? I know popleft and append is O(1) for deque, I just still don't know the overall performant implications of using this method to essentially iterate through a list, with the ability to also remove items in the "list" (deque) with O(1) as well.

Comment: How large is your "very large list", and what can you tell us about the lengths of the inner lists?

Comment: This is an exercise for high scale design for large scale systems, e.g. Facebook/netflix etc. If the answer was 20,000 vs 1 million would it change your answer? Thoughts on my design/solution?

Comment: How long the inner lists are relative to the outer list does affect the answer. And both are good to know.

Comment: Btw, Im not convinced you're asking the right question. Is your input truly a list of deques? Or is building the list of deques only a step in your solution for the *real* task, and the real task doesn't have deques?

Comment: from the post:I have a list of deque, **built from a 2d array**:

Comment: from the post:I have a list of deque, **built from a 2d array**:
The task is, given a list of lists, iterate through the lists and output a value from each list, in order given, until you have exhausted all inner lists. *skip exhausted queues*. So there is a variety of ways to tackle this, I thought my above approach is pretty solid when keeping in mind performance of removing items from lists.

I dont think inner_list.pop(0) is a good idea for the inner lists, too slow. You can also keep a pointer per inner list to track used values. Still have to deal with skipping empty/exhausted outer

Comment: removing items from a list at all is O(n), where it is O(1) in a deque. And if you dont actually remove the items you're keeping the entire list in memory for the entire duration (I'm not sure this is even allowed, need to ask for clarification on the prompt). I think you're focusing on the trivial portion of the problem, the interesting portion is completely skipping exhausted lists. As in, not even iterating over them anymore. Not simply *do nothing* for that iteration, but skip that iteration all together.

Comment: I'd probably try iterators instead of queues. Less memory and faster. But your question is about exhausting queues...

Comment: unpredictable results to alter an iterable while you are iterating on it. So, not a good idea to use an iterator for the outer list. Using an iterator on the inner lists works fine. I think my approach for a queue for the outer list, and .next() inner iterables works too. Like I said, interested to hear your solution for completely skipping inner lists that have been exhausted.

Comment: This could be an interesting and good question, I optimize and benchmark in Python *a lot*. But... the question asks about queues and I wouldn't want to do that, and I also wouldn't want to do this without knowing the sizes. Look at more-itertools, for example. It has *two* different functions for this exact task (well, not for queues), *because* what's faster depends on the sizes.

Comment: Also, started to impl inner lists as iters... there is no has next in python. So you would have to attempt to next(inner_list) before knowing the inner list was exausted. That is an entire iterate cycle wasted for every single empty list by your design

Comment: That's not the fastest way to do it, but I just tried it that way, minimally modifying your solution to use iterators instead of deques, and it became almost twice as fast.

Comment: With a few more optimizations it became about four times as fast as yours.

Comment: What did you do? Can you share the code please? Always down to learn.

Comment: Are you also skipping exhausted lists?

Comment: It "skips" exhausted iterators (by removing them from the container of iterators).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, or if that still adheres to the problem. Do you not want to post your alterations?

Comment: I won't post as it doesn't fit the question, since the question is about queues. (And I'd also want to do proper benchmarking, which I can't because I don't know the sizes.)

Comment: I've edited the post. I don't know why you would argue semantics after I explained the original problem and my solution (that involved queues). I'm assuming you know there is something not quite great about your solution since you wont post it. 

I've created a solution that is 400% faster
Source: Trust me bro

Comment: Huh? This whole time I've been trying to get the question changed so that I *can* post it (and trying to get the sizes from you so that I can do it properly - still missing this).

Comment: I altered the post. It doesnt matter if its 50,000 items in each list or 500,000. Performance will start to decouple for each approach before then. Just go with 50,000 items in the outter queue, with 50,000 items in each of the 50,000 items

Comment: Oh, so... not a lot of very short or even empty inner lists after all? 2.5 billion items takes too much time for my patience, I'll use something smaller but "similar". Is it realistic that the inner lists are all the same (or almost the same) long length? Then skipping exhausted ones saves nothing (or almost nothing), rather missing that point of your question. And then `more_itertools.interleave_longest` might be one of the best options.

Comment: No. You cannot assume they are similar length. The example I am given includes empty lists and single items and long lists. It's meant to be a challenging question. The question specifically asks to skip exhausted queues. This isn't a real problem where I can be flexible on the requirements. This is an interview type question that is meant to be challenging.

Comment: Alright, so no `interleave_longest`. It still affects times/choices of  skipping solutions, though. I'll probably use `data = [list(range(1000, randint(1001, 2000))) for _ in range(1000)]` for benchmarking, i.e., 1000 lists with 1 to 1000 elements.

Answer (score 3):

Benchmark with some solutions:

```
Best three from ten runs:
 145 ms   147 ms   148 ms  columns
 202 ms   203 ms   204 ms  chained_removers
 219 ms   220 ms   221 ms  like_interleave_longest
 302 ms   303 ms   304 ms  with_roundrobin
 313 ms   314 ms   314 ms  iterators
 330 ms   331 ms   333 ms  iterators3
 336 ms   338 ms   338 ms  iterators2
 366 ms   368 ms   369 ms  queues_optimized
 471 ms   474 ms   475 ms  queues_clean
 737 ms   741 ms   746 ms  queues
```

Input was 1000 lists with random lengths from 1000 to 2000.

- `queues` is your original solution (edit: which you had in your question but now deleted).
- `queues_clean` is the same, but without indices, and normal truth value tests instead of length checks.
- `queues_optimized` is an optimized version of `queues_clean`.
- `iterators` is like `queues_optimized` but with iterators instead of queues.
- `iterators2` and `iterators3` are some other versions with iterators I tried, replacing the outer deque with something else.
- `columns` is a different approach. Think of the input data as rows. What you want is the concatenated columns. So prepare one list for each needed column, and then spread every input row across the columns. Finish by collecting by columns.
- `chained_removers` mainly `zip`s all the lists. But it chains little remover iterables behind them, which remove their exhausted iterator and yield a marker which then also gets removed (from the values of the current "column"). Also uses an `OrderedDict` for its doubly-linked list, allowing O(1) time deletions and subsequent O(length) time iteration.
- `with_roundrobin` uses the roundrobin [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). Not sure it counts, as it "skips" exhausted iterators at a potentially very high cost, see below.
- `like_interleave_longest` is like [more_itertools.interleave_longest](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave_longest), but optimized for producing a list. It *doesn't* skip exhausted inner lists, but I include it in the benchmark out of curiousity.

I had originally discarded the roundrobin solution because your question made it look like you had many very short (even empty) inner lists. And there it's terrible, for example for 10000 lists with random lengths from 1 to 5:

```
   3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  like_interleave_longest
   5 ms     6 ms     6 ms  columns
   8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  iterators
   8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  iterators2
   8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  iterators3
   9 ms     9 ms    10 ms  queues_optimized
  12 ms    12 ms    13 ms  queues_clean
  18 ms    18 ms    19 ms  queues
  26 ms    27 ms    29 ms  chained_removers
3642 ms  3750 ms  3812 ms  with_roundrobin
```

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVhtb9tGDP7uX8F1KCylSuAkGzAYc4G2aYt9GrB@NAxBsej4ar1VL4nTYb89I3kn3UmWm3TBsPmDY92RD8mHPPKU4r7e5tnlL0X58BDjBr402GDlxVEd@fMJ0Id/hl9gAcsYaddTPmzyEhSoTPZgZcUUiWmppbJSZZTdoJdg5mks31/5olNi3ZRZmKiqZnwNdLdVCUInTeZew0y7wh@VxbhnM7J5VuRFgpva8zsBB/QsKgrMYmN2Kaorq2J11MYabOV8@GHhGrZBtrAi50bi2p5MLJ3hOsEoc0nV6x1baVR48isQE34LWjXJATNa1folzySk10cJYZjWaRE7woHs9SM2qK7yIGIG7wWbF7VK1VeMvztgA0DOHcTT22@qrRXQro0Spp9DLUHLPSaeTCn7c0Bn@Bw6JYJHyFQ1llGdl72z2C32iOTVHo@dmKGye@6x6UhpQq3YszjNcF@Ht1EiFPKDw3RnwjnQZsl1YEB5Xd73aeznwBr0WgQnEYehWqlOCPdrLGr4VOfFb7Kp8qxvsoiq6tFcXRxLFneE8Vz96/xGibpFi8@fHSKXhey4yPyRrt2mhJr3COJoSv5JWlpfRhLytKT0EjPkXMJ7NGWX/8OUmfzM/rOkdPhLdmXlHM3R/MGrBZw/N3UxJgO789Wx7K3zpEmzXms0S5yV5UoIC@3dI432kkoa8m0mfQ3OgmV@115m5o47bXt1bhJBayZgJT@A2XhFMKqWZGCjMx@MEGZNbx0NcxupDOOwxDS/xf4oSKNyh9w08@vPuG7nPWsZabqozY@Qq2wruFeYxAbs4Aj8XsZYYnylOnwpRKKQw8KsSVkWXbf61aO4dCQKj7izjn3rfqP71XwhN7IOyoFnH6SCK/biqyq8Ezu59AYN4n61mQuehYNftaFj50UnJy3oqfI0aADSDaowy@sA2rUSC4y4UTCD/shZui4x2k3GLWiQY@kv8yaLy/ya2NMRXifYEvHC2Zy@eftuGsD0ir/ef5j6cHr6Gt7AFbyHt/AB3r0QlR/hD1yrAmFNOSW8GOocPmJe3iB8inY7pR2hrIbRutZDoyNNTHe9jItjfU@3WtmkL/8sDKW1hKZXdV3KKur0Wvj58fnOGAzHKGLvME26cHnT@54xziRwFUK9ta0X7hA@N/QSgvttRH@Jmk2ZpyIjYZ71MByGToeNb8BOlag1StOlUrF6VCaS4TtVb0Mnk85BMvUgU8gtBDOHRD1ROwxVRlHQ@8UthklOzY7kH20TBny5P2B93x6qDkwsBrBRSSLlujClfqjKmvtqeO5ouQI6MsaV1WSyabK1NGrnUh@4F3x5XeqtdO8UQb9JDR4vBs@XgTsbzMOgqerVQSb04hF@gwkHIQWiUuRaT4u8rLn5RjxqebWEqJJtLUhjKKY/RpCfCDaAattsNomRuVYVZaiVUVlFf/QO@Z/QFhVzZW3Jy5PTobUoh17nedIJSiEGoCsx0NEHXWtr@1fgplwj5UV73zAOSeOjwuN3fkqerkwZr@ez2SwA/oZXbXDeeQA/u/1wMJJZekZD@Ol4snjBWt9GZVDcF8zlAqTWlrOVPhMTFucl1pAtfUroHkK0yYoWhMUCNMZkwlnkcv2Tt@dgbhc9lL8mB36Y82cy7ImYnaEjPkgjnJEdtuf0NOuUFTs/FNP14omzS9ZZBSx3Spj9sFmM3s3FckDXt/uF6JzdYG18Lkrm@8SbvvyJrgYVTOEleDWcwDle6n/@SGN2TC3nlyu6DfFvHgRRimHoPzz8DQ)):

```
def queues(data):
    data_q = [deque(i) for i in data ]
    data_i = deque([i for i in range(len(data_q))])
    return_list = []
    while len(data_i) > 0:
        index = data_i.popleft()
        return_list.append(data_q[index].popleft())
        if len(data_q[index]) != 0:
            data_i.append(index)
    return return_list

def queues_clean(data):
    queues = deque(map(deque, data))
    result = []
    while queues:
        queue = queues.popleft()
        result.append(queue.popleft())
        if queue:
            queues.append(queue)
    return result

def queues_optimized(data):
    queues = deque(map(deque, data))
    queues_pop = queues.popleft
    queues_push = queues.append
    result = []
    result_append = result.append
    while queues:
        queue = queues_pop()
        result_append(queue.popleft())
        if queue:
            queues_push(queue)
    return result

def iterators(data):
    iterators = deque(map(iter, data))
    iterators_pop = iterators.popleft
    iterators_push = iterators.append
    result = []
    result_append = result.append
    next_value = next
    while iterators:
        iterator = iterators_pop()
        try:
            result_append(next_value(iterator))
            iterators_push(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    return result

def iterators2(data):
    iterators = list(map(iter, data))
    result = []
    result_append = result.append
    next_value = next
    while iterators:
        alive = []
        keep = alive.append
        for iterator in iterators:
            try:
                result_append(next_value(iterator))
                keep(iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                pass
        iterators = alive
    return result

def iterators3(data):
    iterators = list(map(iter, data))
    result = []
    result_append = result.append
    next_value = next
    while iterators:
        keep = 0
        for iterator in iterators:
            try:
                result_append(next_value(iterator))
                iterators[keep] = iterator
                keep += 1
            except StopIteration:
                pass
        del iterators[keep:]
    return result

def columns(data):
    columns = [[] for _ in range(max(map(len, data)))]
    for row in data:
        deque(map(list.append, columns, row), 0)
    result = []
    for column in columns:
        result += column
    return result

def chained_removers(data):
    marker = object()
    def remover(i):
        del iterators[i]
        yield marker
    iterators = OrderedDict()
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        iterators[i] = chain(d, remover(i))
    result = []
    while alive := len(iterators):
        for values in zip(*iterators.values()):
            if len(iterators) < alive:
                result += compress(values, map(is_not, values, repeat(marker)))
                break
            result += values
    return result

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))

def with_roundrobin(data):
    return list(roundrobin(*data))

def like_interleave_longest(data):
    marker = object()
    return [x
            for xs in zip_longest(*data, fillvalue=marker)
            for x in xs
            if x is not marker]

funcs = [
    queues,
    queues_clean,
    queues_optimized,
    iterators,
    iterators2,
    iterators3,
    columns,
    chained_removers,
    with_roundrobin,
    like_interleave_longest,
]

from timeit import default_timer as time
from random import randint, shuffle
from bisect import insort
from collections import deque, OrderedDict
from itertools import cycle, islice, chain, compress, repeat, zip_longest
from operator import is_not

data = [list(range(1000, 1000 + randint(1, 5)))
        for _ in range(10000)]

data = [list(range(1000, 1000 + randint(1000, 2000)))
        for _ in range(1000)]

expect = funcs[0](data)
for func in funcs:
    assert func(data) == expect

times = {func: [] for func in funcs}
for _ in range(10):
    shuffle(funcs)
    for func in funcs:
        t0 = time()
        func(data)
        t1 = time()
        insort(times[func], t1 - t0)
for func in sorted(funcs, key=times.get):
    print(*('%4d ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in times[func][:3]), func.__name__)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help bro. You're a god! This is awesome. I don't think the columns approach would satisfy the exercise, though it is the fastest. Seems negligible perf gains from iters to queues... but your optimization def almost doubles the speed of a queue approach, you're the best!

Comment: @throwaway2018 What's the issue with `columns`? It's indeed quite different, but it does do something equivalent to "skipping". Yes, compared to the *optimized* queues solution, and with these much longer inner lists, the iterator solutions aren't that much faster, though they still are faster. And they take much less memory, only a small iterator object per inner list instead of a full copy as a deque.

Comment: For `columns`, a better way to connect a list of lists might be to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: @MechanicPig I tried that, it was slower.

Comment: @MechanicPig But I just added another solution (`chained_removers`), which does use `chain` and more itertools (in particular `compress`, one of my favorites).

Comment: @KellyBundy the reason i was popping and appending a queue of indexes instead of the queue itself was i was under the impression that popping and appending an enormous queue was not very performant - i guess that isnt the case?

e.g   a =     deque(list[ *1 million ints*]),  b=deque(a)  while(1):     b.append(b.pop())

Comment: @throwaway2018 Ah, ok. No, that's not the case. When you pop/append, that just pops/appends a reference to the queue object, in O(1) time. Doesn't "copy" or "move" its whole contents.

Comment: Thank you! I have learned a lot from you. Really appreciate all the time you put into responding and reviewing strategies. Upvoted answer.