# Merging 2 list elementwise vertically python

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[5,6]
```

I want to merge to make list c such that final answer is

```
c=[1,5,2,6,3,4]
```

I don't want to use any built-in modules I tried zip but it stops at shorter list

Comment: @mozway Uh no, if you notice the lists are interleaved, not concatenated.

Comment: @AidenChow I know, I had a brain freeze (already removed my comment)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most optimal way to exhaust a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72332193/most-optimal-way-to-exhaust-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`more_itertools.roundrobin`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.roundrobin):

```
# pip install more-itertools
from more_itertools import roundrobin

c = list(roundrobin(a,b))
```

output: `[1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4]`

without installing more-itertools, you can also use the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

Comment: Lovely *more_itertools* .  nice to see another one. +1

Answer (score 1):

Without using any builtin modules, this is probably the simplest — zip what is zippable, concatenate the rest:

```
s = min(len(a), len(b))
result = [e for pair in zip(a, b) for e in pair] + a[s:] + b[s:]
```

Comment: This is fun, but would be impractical to generalize to 3 lists or more

Comment: @mozway True. It solves the problem as posted, no more and no less. The generalised solution is, as you posted, the round robin algorithm; if you forbid imports, then the best solution is to literally copy/paste `roundrobin` from the sources.

Comment: Yes, I just though of that and added the code ;) (I personally like more-itertools so usually have it as an install)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way without any built-in modules:

```
def merge(a, b):
  shorter_list = b if len(a) > len(b) else a
  longer_list = a if len(a) > len(b) else b
  return sum(zip(a, b), ()) + longer_list[len(shorter_list):]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `loops` only

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[5,6]
 
i = 0
j = 0
 
result =[]
while i<len(a) or j <len(b):
    if i <len(a):
        result.append(a[i])
        i+=1
    if j < len(b):
        result.append(b[j])
        j+=1
 
print(result) # [1,5,2,6,3,4]
```